# Vector Quantization Algorithms used to provide observation sequences for Hidden Markov Models

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, gesture-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I am currently building a gesture recognition application. I am extracting certain features from the hand (such as [angle of motion, width: length ratio,...]). This is my feature vector. But obviously, one cannot have an observation of such vectors as input to a Hidden Markov Model.

General Info: A gesture is made up of a set of Postures.

Thus I found a paper which suggests that I do Vector Quantization. My aim is to use some sort of algorithm where I feed a feature vector from one side, and obtain an integer or simple value (which maps a particular state/posture).  I would then feed these set of symbols (mapping the complete gesture) to the hidden Markov model (

One algorithm is the K Means clustering. Unfortunately, if for example I would like to recognize X amount of symbols, and I decided to go for creating a cluster for each symbol, K means creates a MAXIMUM of X clusters, so this cannot be used to map each state/posture I have.

I am thus thinking that I need some sort of clustering algorithm, where if possible, it can be supervised so I dictate that these sets of feature vectors map to posture A and the others map to posture B.

Does there exist some form of supervised clustering/ classification algorithm where I input a set of vectors [angle, width, height] and obtain a simple symbol e.g. 'A'?

The following is some sample data I just generated:

Posture A:
[angle of ellipse surrounding it, height:width ratio]

- 0.802985 33.909615
- 0.722824    31.209663
- 0.734535    30.206722
- 0.68397 31.838253
- 0.713706    34.29641
- 0.688798    30.603661
- 0.721395    34.880161

Posture B:
[structured the same as posture A]

- 0.474164 16.077467

  - 0.483104 14.526289
  - 0.478904 14.800572
  - 0.483134 14.523611
  - 0.480608 14.41159
  - 0.481552  15.563665
  - 0.497951  15.563585

Comment: Why not recognize each basic hand position with just a dumb (normalized, 1-vs-many) logistic classifier?  Or perhaps a 1-hidden-layer neural net?  It's entirely possible a simple model would work here, which you could then feed into the HMM

Comment: Thank you for the information! Yes I'm now testing my data on a program which consists of various classification algorithms (Rapid Miner (such as Decision Trees, even neural networks, although I didn't try them yet) and see how good my features really are! Then I will find a tool or implement them in my app! Thanks a lot :)